# multithreading in jenkins pipeline

Tags: multithreading, jenkins, groovy, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline

Im new in groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline that loads hundreds of mocks.
I want to boost up my building times, so I thought maybe I should use multithreading for the job.
problem is, I couldnt find any examples for multithreading a single stage.
only found the parallel option, but in my understanding, its only suitable if I want to run multiple stages at once. not for running multiple threads at the same stage.
any ideas?

```
stage("mocks") {
    //load mocks
}
```

thanks!

Comment: in scripted pipelines you can use the parallel step to run code which is not in a stage in parallel. I guess if you put it in a `script` block you could do the same in a declarative pipeline.